# THREE.js - Drawing large amount of objects dynamically?

Tags: three.js

I have a large amount of 3D objects (i.e. asteroids) that I would like to render. I know I can merge all geometry into a single one OR I can use a buffer-geometry (are these the same thing?).

However, my asteroid objects always come and go. At any given second more asteroids could be created and placed into the scene.

*** Question ***
How to handle rendering this dynamic set of objects without having to re-create buffers or merge geometries (as these take a big hit on performance)?

I suspect that either the dynamic nature of the scene or the buffering must go.

Comment: How many objects are you talking about and how many faces does each object have? FYI `buffer-geometry` is not the same concept as `merged-geometry` even though the later could be implemented with the former.

Comment: i didnt say they were the same concepts. which is why is used the term "OR". Regarding the objects, im simply using BoxGeometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this is to merge all the asteroids into one geometry, but make note where each individual asteroid lies in the merged geometry (index + count). Then when an asteroid needs to be deleted, just set the position data of the relevant segment for that asteroid to 0. Eg, suppose if the merged geometry is from 3 asteroids, asteroid A from 0 to 10, B from 10 to 20; C 20 to 30. To delete asteroid B is to just setting the position data from 10 to 20 in the merged geometry to 0.

If you need to dynamically "create" new asteroids, you also need to store the segments you created holes at in your merged geometry. Continuing from the example above, if you need to add asteroid D you just fill position data from 10 to 20 (from "deleting" B) to whatever D is. Obviously, if there is no more segment holes left when you need to create a new asteroid, you need to enlarge the entire merged geometry and handle accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I dont think i really follow your explanation. In short, you are suggesting creating a buffer that is as large as i would potentially require? I dont think this is a good idea for my situation. It seems too much of a hack without potential to be very limiting (i.e. inflexible).

Comment: As large as the maximum number of asteroids you need to display at once. Lets say your merged geometry looks like this where each asteroid requires 2 elems in the merged geometry buffer: [A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D]. Deleting B from being draw is simply zeroing B from the merged geometry buffer: [A,A,0,0,C,C,D,D]. Yes there might be space inefficiencies but the trade off in performance is well worth it.

Comment: Inflexible, maybe. But those early games (and modern games as well) usually have some limit on the maximum number of ___ you can display at once for a reason. :)